# IDispatch null pointer exception while creating Active Directory user

Tags: c++, windows, server, active-directory, ldap

I am writing a C++ native method to create an Active Directory user. I am getting a null pointer exception . This code is exactly the same as the code in the [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-creating-a-user).

I have mentioned in a comment on which line I get the error:

```cpp
HRESULT CreateUserFromADs(
    LPCWSTR pwszName,
    LPCWSTR pwszSAMAccountName,
    LPCWSTR pwszInitialPassword)
{
    HRESULT hr;


    CoInitialize(NULL);
    IADsContainer* pUsers = NULL;
    hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://WIN-F94H2MP3UJR.Test.local/CN=Users,DC=Test,DC=local", L"Administrator", L"Pass@12",
        ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, // For secure authentication
        IID_IADs,
        (void**)&pUsers);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        IDispatch* pDisp = NULL;

        CComBSTR sbstrName = "CN=";
        sbstrName += pwszName;

        // Create the new object in the User folder.
        hr = pUsers->Create(CComBSTR("user"), sbstrName, &pDisp);

        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            IADsUser* padsUser = NULL;

            // Get the IADs interface.

        // Am getting null pointer exception here.
            hr = pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IADsUser,
                (void**)&padsUser);

            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                CComBSTR sbstrProp;
                /*
                The sAMAccountName property is required on operating system
                versions prior to Windows Server 2003.
                The Windows Server 2003 operating system will create a
                sAMAccountName value if one is not specified.
                */
                CComVariant svar;
                svar = pwszSAMAccountName;
                sbstrProp = "sAMAccountName";
                hr = padsUser->Put(sbstrProp, svar);

                /*
                Commit the new user to persistent memory.
                The user does not exist until this is called.
                */
                hr = padsUser->SetInfo();

                /*
                Set the initial password. This must be done after
                SetInfo is called because the user object must
                already exist on the server.
                */
                hr = padsUser->SetPassword(CComBSTR(pwszInitialPassword));

                /*
                Set the pwdLastSet property to zero, which forces the
                user to change the password the next time they log on.
                */
                sbstrProp = "pwdLastSet";
                svar = 0;
                hr = padsUser->Put(sbstrProp, svar);

                /*
                Enable the user account by removing the
                ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE flag from the userAccountControl
                property. Also, remove the ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD and
                ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD flags from the
                userAccountControl property.
                */
                svar.Clear();
                sbstrProp = "userAccountControl";
                hr = padsUser->Get(sbstrProp, &svar);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    svar = svar.lVal & ~(ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE |
                        ADS_UF_PASSWD_NOTREQD |
                        ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD);

                    hr = padsUser->Put(sbstrProp, svar);
                    hr = padsUser->SetInfo();
                }

                hr = padsUser->put_AccountDisabled(VARIANT_FALSE);
                hr = padsUser->SetInfo();

                padsUser->Release();
            }

            pDisp->Release();
        }

        pUsers->Release();
    }
    CoUninitialize();

    return hr;
}
```

Error message is

> Exception thrown: read access violation.
> pDisp was nullptr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking `ADsOpenObject()` for an `IADs*` interface pointer, but you are storing it in an `IADsContainer*` variable. That is a type mismatch, `IADs` and `IADsContainer` are unrelated interfaces. So, when you call `pUsers->Create()`, you are not actually calling `IADsContainer::Create()` at all, you are actually calling `IADs::SetInfo()` instead, which does not assign anything to `pDisp`, which is why it remains NULL.

The Microsoft doc you linked to does not make that mistake, it asks `ADsOpenObject()` for `IADsContainer` instead of `IADs`.

The `IID` you request **must** match the variable type you receive into. So, change `IID_IADs` to `IID_IADsContainer`:

```
IADsContainer* pUsers = NULL;
hr = ADsOpenObject(...,
        IID_IADsContainer,
        (void**)&pUsers);
```

You should consider using the [`IID_PPV_ARGS()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-iid_ppv_args) macro to avoid making this mistake again:

```
IADsContainer* pUsers = NULL;
hr = ADsOpenObject(...,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&pUsers));
```

---

On a side note, your `CreateUserFromADs()` function has no business calling `CoInitialize()` directly, so you should remove that call. It is the responsibility of the calling thread to call `CoInitialize/Ex()` to establish its concurrency model *before* performing any COM-related activities. It is not up to functions to decide what concurrency model to use on behalf of the calling thread.